# Adding some custom sample data to a TextView

Tags: android, textview

Google introduced [Preview with sample data in the Layout Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor?utm_source=android-studio&utm_medium=studio-assistant#sample-data) in the last Android Studio update 3.2. However the listing is limited to 13 attributes in Textview.

[image]

My question is how to add custom attributes like price, age, etc?

Comment: check this: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-tools-attributes-listitem-sample-data-rocks-bbf49aaa9f07 The head **My own sample data** "But even better! you can use Json object to show more complex data".